# maven - replace a string before copying file to another directory

Tags: maven

I'm copying sql files to another directory using

```
<copy todir="../directory" filtering="true">
        <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/sql/creation/scripts" includes="*.sql"/>
        // i want to modify the file content of init.sql before copying
    </copy>
```

with init.sql

```
create sequence SCHEMA_NAME.SEQ_APP
```

i want to replace SCHEMA_NAME by $1. before copying it.

How can i do that ?

Thank you

Comment: First put the scripts into `src/main/resources` and activate filtering...

Answer (score 0):

The general way accomplish this is via Maven Resource Filtering - where the "filtering" is about replacing placeholders with actual values: https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/

But you'll need to change the value in your SQL-file...

Comment: I added <filterset>
                <filter token="SCHEMA_NAME" value="$1."/>
            </filterset>  but doesn't work

Comment: I used <replace file="${project.basedir}/sql/creation/scripts/init.sql"
                 token="SCHEMA_NAME" value="$1."/> before copy and it works !